# Disable href tag when value = declared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable a href tag when the link of it is # , the reason i want to do this is because i have lots of post on my webpage that have links poiting to other sites that are my partners. 
When i make a post i have a template that make it easier on me to put information on it and have the href link ready if anyone site that has to do with the post want a partnership and i link it to them .
Some of my old post have href tags with # value on it and when i click on them they open up my page on another tab so thats why i would like to disable it if possible with javascript (anyone other script language that can do the job is fine too)

Thanks

Comment: @RobScott: Both will fail.

Comment: @RobScott: Kevin's passes an invalid string to `gEBTN` and then pretends that the result (if it worked) has a `.forEach` method. Ivan's makes the second mistake of Kevin's.

Comment: @squint you were right of course. Updated mine to work, even if there's no element (for IE > 8) http://stackoverflow.com/a/40185612/5095829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be:

```
var emptyAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]');

for (var i = 0; i < emptyAnchors.length; i++) {
    emptyAnchors[i].addEventListener('click', preventDefaultEvent);
}

function preventDefaultEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This will prevent the default behavior on a link click (open the href target).

Answer (score 0):

You can select your a tag with the specific # href

**ES6 syntax**

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a[href='#']");
```

**ES5 syntax**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a[href='#']");
```

then add a preventDefault() on the event of each element to make sure the default behaviour won't be executed.

**ES6 syntax**

```
elements.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**ES5 syntax**

```
elements.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want you can just add css to make the a tag lose its default style

```
a[href="#"] {
  color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: you should maybe also add the ES5 variation to declare the variable, as let is ES6 only.

Comment: Oh you're right, thanks for pointing that out! Let has become such routine :')

Comment: My ES6 variable declaration should even be const, not let.